# Sql specify query to multiply by latest value on subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I want to get the cost of the total stock I have in my client's stores.

Stock information is stored in the MovStockTotal table (plainly as 'Stock'),
The cost of merchandise purchased is stored in the CompraLinea table as 'CostoImp' (price+tax).
both store information by article id ['idarticulo']  (there are many records per article on the CompraLinea table since it stores every purchase ever made, but the MovStockTotal table has one per article (IdArticulo), per store deposit (IdDeposito) since it is constantly updated to reflect current values).

I want to run this query by article section, so I need my query to join the Documento table (all tables are joined to this by their 'IdDocumento' column)

So far, I have this query, which runs fine:

```
select IdDeposito,
       sum(stock) as stocktotal,
       sum(Stock * CostoImp) as costostocktotal
  from movstocktotal
  join Articulo
    on MovStockTotal.IdArticulo = Articulo.IdArticulo
  join compralinea
    on articulo.IdArticulo = CompraLinea.IdArticulo
 where idseccion = 101
   and IdDeposito in (30, 38, 40, 44, 50, 60, 70, 90, 100)
 group by IdDeposito
```

The problem I have is I need the query to take the CostoImp of the latest purchase made (the CompraLinea table has purchases made going as far back as 2008, so if it takes costs of purchases made then my results will be way off).

I tried introducing a subquery to order the data

```
select IdDeposito,
       sum(stock) as stocktotal,
       sum(Stock * CostoImp) as costostocktotal
  from movstocktotal
  join Articulo
    on MovStockTotal.IdArticulo = Articulo.IdArticulo
  join (select *
          from compralinea
          join documento
            on compralinea.iddocumento = documento.iddocumento
         order by date) as x
 where idseccion = 101
   and IdDeposito in (30, 38, 40, 44, 50, 60, 70, 90, 100)
 group by IdDeposito
```

But it gives me syntax errors [specifically on 'where' but it doesn't say why] (unsurprising as I'm just winging it here)

I thought about creating an associative subquery to get the latest cost for each article and use that table's value to calculate my results:

```
select IdDeposito,
       sum(stock) as stocktotal,
       sum(Stock * CostoImp) as costostocktotal
  from VsBoremix.dbo.movstocktotal
  join VsBoremix.dbo.Articulo
    on MovStockTotal.IdArticulo = Articulo.IdArticulo
  join (select idarticulo, costoImp
          from VsBoremix.dbo.CompraLinea
          join vsboremix.dbo.Documento
            on CompraLinea.IdDocumento = documento.IdDocumento
         order by fecha) as x
    on articulo.IdArticulo = x.IdArticulo
 where idseccion = 101
   and IdDeposito in (30, 38, 40, 44, 50, 60, 70, 90, 100)
 group by IdDeposito
```

But I get this error:

```
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.
```

How would I specify for the query to take the latest cost for the sum (stock*costoImp) and not just the first one it finds?

Comment: What table is the field "fecha" on? Also is the "latest cost" where the "fecha" value is highest for each combination of idarticulo and costoimp?

Comment: Fecha appears only on the Documento table. The latest cost would be the 'costoImp' on the latest Compralinea record (select top 1 costoImp from compralinea join documento on iddocumento, order by documento.fecha desc) for each 'IdArticulo'

Comment: What tables have the "idarticulo" and "costoImp" columns?

Comment: IdArticulo is present in the MovStockTotal, Compralinea and Articulo tables. CostoImp is only present in the CompraLinea table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of toying around, I found a way to make my query work. Here's my result:

```
    select sum(a.costoimp*movstocktotal.stock)
FROM     vsboremix.dbo.CompraLinea AS a 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT compralinea.IdArticulo, MAX(compralinea.IdDocumento) AS iddocumento, IdListaEmpresa
    FROM     vsboremix.dbo.Compralinea join vsboremix.dbo.documento on CompraLinea.IdDocumento = documento.IdDocumento join VsBoremix.dbo.articulo on compralinea.IdArticulo=articulo.IdArticulo
    where IdDeposito in(30,38,40,44,50,60,70,90,100) and compralinea.CostoImp>0.0 and idseccion=101
    GROUP BY compralinea.IdArticulo, IdListaEmpresa) AS b ON b.IdArticulo = a.IdArticulo AND b.iddocumento = a.IdDocumento 
join vsboremix.dbo.movstocktotal on a.IdArticulo = MovStockTotal.IdArticulo and b.IdListaEmpresa=MovStockTotal.IdEmpresa
```

I think the problem I had were incompletely specified joins (not saying inner/outer or because I would equate article ID's but not the document id's and this might have caused duplicates).

I decided to use the max of the document ID's since these are added as they come, they're inherently ordered by date and this spared me an extra join.

Thanks anyways for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
select IdDeposito,
       sum(stock) as stocktotal,
       sum(Stock * CostoImp) as costostocktotal
  from VsBoremix.dbo.movstocktotal
  join VsBoremix.dbo.Articulo
    on MovStockTotal.IdArticulo = Articulo.IdArticulo
  join (select idarticulo, costoImp, max(fecha) as max_fecha
          from VsBoremix.dbo.CompraLinea
          join vsboremix.dbo.Documento
            on CompraLinea.IdDocumento = documento.IdDocumento
         group by idarticulo, costoImp) as x
    on articulo.IdArticulo = x.IdArticulo
 where idseccion = 101
   and IdDeposito in (30, 38, 40, 44, 50, 60, 70, 90, 100)
 group by IdDeposito
```

This changes your inline view with the alias "x" so that only the highest fecha is shown for each idarticulo and costoImp combination.

Comment: Gives the same results. For some reason the stock results are all actually multiplied by 25 - but even if that wasn't an issue, I checked the code against a single item instead of every item in a category and where the price should be 8.02 it gives 6.62
Another article's stock is multiplied by 8 and the price comes to ~20.79 instead of 22.08
Neither price appears as a purchas eprice in any record for these articles in the compralinea table...